# If $\vec{\alpha}''\cdot \vec{u}=0$ in $I$ for some $\vec{u}\in \mathbb{R}^3$, prove $\tau+\left(\frac{\kappa}{\tau}\right)'=0.$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

> Let $\vec{\alpha}:I\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be an arclength parametrized curve   such that
> $\kappa(s)>0$ and $\tau(s)\neq 0$ for all $s \in I.$ If $\vec{\alpha}''(s)\cdot \vec{u}=0$ for all $s\in I$ for some $\vec{u}\in \mathbb{R}^3$, prove that
> $$\tau(s)+\left(\frac{\kappa(s)}{\tau(s)}\right)'=0.$$

*Attempt*. One thought is that since $\vec{\alpha}''(s)\cdot \vec{u}=0$ for all $s\in I$,
we get $\vec{\alpha}'\cdot \vec{u}$ is constant in $I$ and the curve is a generalized helix. In that case $\frac{\kappa}{\tau}$ is constant and the desired equality becomes $\tau =0$, which contradicts the given hypothesis about the torsion. Is there a flaw in the above argument?

Another thought was that curve $\vec{\alpha}''$ is planar, so it's torsion is zero, i.e.
$(\vec{\alpha}''',\vec{\alpha}'''',\vec{\alpha}''''')=0.$

Thank in advance for the help.

Comment: The condition $\alpha' \cdot u = \mathrm{const}$ is not enough to conclude that $\alpha$ resembles a helix. I can't say more without relevant definitions - those of $\kappa$ and $\tau$.

Comment: Here $\kappa$ and $\tau$ represent the curvature and torsion of the curve, respectively.

Comment: If $\vec{\alpha}'\cdot \vec{u}=\cos \theta=const$, then either $\theta\in (0,\pi)$ and $\vec{\alpha}$ is a helix, either $\theta=0$ or $\pi$ so  $\vec{\alpha}'$ and $\vec{u}$ are parallel and the trace of $\vec{\alpha}$ is part of a line (which is not our case since $k(s)>0$ for all $s$).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I think that if $\beta \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is an arclength parametrization of **any** curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\alpha(t) = (t,\beta(t))/\sqrt{2}$ satisfies the required condition with $u=(1,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your argument is correct  and that the statement is flawed. One has: $\kappa(s)/\tau(s)$ is constant. Here are my calculations:

We may assume that $u=(0,0,1)$ so that $n(s)=(\cos \phi(s),\sin \phi(s),0)$, for some function $\phi(s)$. Now, $t(s)\cdot n(s)=0$, so $t(s)=(-\alpha \sin \phi(s), \alpha \cos \phi(s), \beta)$ with $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$. A priory $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depends upon $s$ but here is where the auxiliary condition enters: $t'(s)\cdot u=0$ so $\beta$ is a constant, whence also $\alpha$.

Now $b=t\times n= (\beta \sin \phi(s), -\beta \cos \phi(s), \alpha)$, and then taking derivatives you verify: $t'(s) = \kappa(s) n(s)$ with $\kappa(s)=-\alpha \phi'(s)$ and $b'(s)=-\tau(s) \phi'(s)$ with $\tau(s) = -\beta \phi'(s)$. In other words, $\kappa(s)/\tau(s) = \alpha/\beta$ is a constant.